# How to filter through table using keywords and access that row of information

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet that lists all the engineering standard procedures (ESP) my company owns. I am trying to add another sheet to the Excel document to be used as a search bar so that when my colleagues and I type in a keyword that matches the description of the ESP (which is included in the original document) It lists the possible matches and includes the hyperlink for those esps (which is included in the original document), just in a different column then the description. Any help would be appreciated thank you!

I sort of have a solution for my problem, but it does not show any hyperlinks in the extraction table and I am limited to using one column for my data array, which is essentially my description column. So I have to manually re-enter all the esp #'s to that column.

I placed three different components in the new sheet that I added to the excel document. One component is just an two cells that are labeled search, where I could type in the key words I would like to search.

The second component is a count cell with the following formula :

`=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A4:B95,"*"&B7&"*")`

and the last is my extraction table with the following formula :

`=IF(G5>B11,"",INDEX(Sheet1!B4:B95,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(Sheet1!B4:B95)-ROW(Sheet1!$B$5)+2)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B7,Sheet1!B4:B95)),G5)))`

I basically did what this tutorial told me to do link : https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-all-partial-matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$7,AGGREGATE(15,3,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$2,$A$2:$A$7)),ROW($A$2:$A$7),""),ROW(A1))),"")
```

Enter with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Formula in `E2`:

```
=HYPERLINK(IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$7,AGGREGATE(15,3,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$2,$A$2:$A$7)),ROW($A$2:$A$7),""),ROW(A1))),""))
```

Again, enter with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Drag both formula's down

Comment: This is by the way, but how do you record the GIFs, please?

Comment: @AAA, I'm using [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/), quite handy.

Comment: If I add another row that is just keywords would I be able to link that in a new sheet. For example I now have three rows, one that has the title of the ESP, one that has keywords that describe that ESP, and a last one that has the hyperlink for that ESP. Is there anyway for all three corresponding rows to come up once I do a partial word search?